# Запрос на выборку с исключением по времени и по другой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

есть две таблицы:

1. new_task

```
CREATE TABLE admin_website.new_task (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  quantity int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  status int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  link varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

2. api_task_user

```
CREATE TABLE admin_website.api_task_user (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_task int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

В первой таблице находятся задания для пользователя.

Во второй информация о том, какой пользователь (`user_id`) выполнил задание (`id_task`) в какое время (`date`)

Допустим, в первой таблице сейчас находятся вот такие задания:

```
id  link                    quantity    status   link 
1   https://vk.com/         5000        1        https://vk.com/
2   https://yandex.com/     5000        1        https://yandex.com/
3   https://google.com/     3000        1        https://google.com/
```

Я буду пользователем с `id` = 1 и во второй таблице хранятся вот такие данные:

```
id      user_id  id_task date
4       1        1       Вт 31.03.20 17:28:47
5       1        2       Ср 24.06.20 17:29:36
```

Т.е. я выполнил первое и второе задание, но **не** выполнил третье.

Так же есть условия:

1. В выборку должны включаться записи, которые уже выполнил пользователь, но только через **24 часа**

2. Задания у которых `status` = 1
3. Задания у которых `quantity` > 0

Набросал вот такой код:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   new_task n 
   LEFT JOIN
      api_task_user atu 
      ON atu.id_task = n.id 
WHERE
   n.status = 1 
   AND n.quantity > 0 
   AND 
   (
      atu.user_id IS NULL 
      OR atu.user_id = 1
   )
   AND 
   (
      date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
      OR date IS NULL
   )
ORDER BY
   n.quantity
```

Он всё правильно отрабатывает до тех пор, пока не появляется пользователь 2 и начинает выполнять задания, которые ещё не выполнил я, тогда же пропадают записи, которые раньше выводила вот эта строка:

`atu.user_id IS NULL`

Потому что там уже не `NULL`, а id второго пользователя.

В общем вот и весь вопрос: Как сделать правильную выборку тех заданий, которые пользователь ещё не выполнил и включить туда те, которые от уже выполнил, но с того момента прошло 24 часа?

**Версия сервера: MySQL 5.1.73**

**UPD:**

Когда мой запрос выдал нужный результат, решил добавить новые задания, что бы проверить окончательно, что запрос работает правильно, добавил вот такую строку

```
id  link                    quantity    status   link 
4   https://asf.ru          2000        1        https://asf.ru
```

В итоге мой запрос не показывает, что это задание доступно, хотя должен был.

---

Запрос @timur-irdyneev Выдаёт следующее:

```
id  name            quantity   status  link             id
4   https://asf.ru  2000       1       https://asf.ru   (null)  ...
1   https://vk.com/ 5000       1       https://vk.com   4   ...
```

Что тоже не верно, поскольку нет задания:

```
id  name
3   https://google.com/
```

Скорее всего из-за того, что его выполнял пользователь 2

**UPD 2:**

```
--
-- Дата скрипта: Ср 24.06.20 17:18:09
-- Версия сервера: 5.1.73
-- Версия клиента: 4.1
--


SET NAMES 'AUTO';

INSERT INTO admin_website.api_task_user(id, user_id, id_task, date) VALUES
(4, 1, 1, '2020-03-31 17:28:47'),
(5, 1, 2, '2020-06-24 12:29:36'),
(13, 2, 3, '2020-03-31 17:28:47'),
(14, 2, 2, '2020-03-31 17:28:47'),
(17, 1, 5, '2020-06-24 12:29:36'),
(18, 2, 4, '2020-06-24 17:09:35'),
(19, 2, 5, '2020-03-31 17:28:47');


INSERT INTO admin_website.new_task(id, name, quantity, status, link) VALUES
(1, 'https://vk.com/', 5000, 1, 'https://vk.com/'),
(2, 'https://yandex.com/', 5000, 1, 'https://yandex.com/'),
(3, 'https://google.com/', 3000, 1, 'https://google.com/'),
(4, 'https://asf.ru', 2000, 1, 'https://asf.ru'),
(5, 'https://ok.com', 1000, 1, 'https://ok.com');
```

Comment: Условие `atu.user_id = 1` перенесите в ON вашего LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте такой вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM new_task nt
  LEFT JOIN api_task_user atu ON atu.id_task = nt.id
WHERE nt.status = 1
  AND nt.quantity > 0
  AND (atu.id is null or atu.user_id = 1)
  AND (atu.date is null or atu.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY nt.quantity
```

**UPD:2**

```
select * from new_task nt
  LEFT JOIN (
      select * from api_task_user atu
      where atu.user_id=1 AND atu.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ) atu ON atu.id_task = nt.id
WHERE nt.status = 1
  AND nt.quantity > 0
```

**UPD:3** с учетом последнего обновления описания

```
select * from new_task nt
  INNER JOIN (
    select * from api_task_user atu
    where atu.user_id is null
      or (atu.user_id = 1 AND atu.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  ) atu ON atu.id_task = nt.id
WHERE nt.status = 1
  AND nt.quantity > 0
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает( Сейчас пытаюсь понять почему

Comment: какой результат выдает запрос?

Comment: Дополнил ответ с моим и вашим запросами

Comment: ок, добавил еще один вариант, чтобы обойтись без UNION

Comment: Этот вариант тоже не работает, выдаёт все строки, хотя не должен

Comment: как понимаю наличие записи в api_task_user обязательно, обновил запрос
предыдущие запросы выдавали полностью свободные задачи без наличия записи в api_task_user

Comment: Вот что получается в итоге: http://prntscr.com/t5o2yf

Comment: select * from new_task nt
  INNER JOIN (
    select * from api_task_user atu
    where atu.user_id is null or atu.user_id = 1
  ) atu ON atu.id_task = nt.id
WHERE nt.status = 1
  AND nt.quantity > 0 AND (atu.date is null or atu.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: Результат точно такой же(

Comment: можно дамп данных?  и правильный набор выходных данных? чтобы понять желаемый результат

Comment: Добавил в вопрос, входные данные - по сути только id пользователя, 1 или 2 для теста, в конечном варианте - естественно будет намного больше

Comment: можно эталонные **выходные данные** для пользователя 1 и 2?  
у меня  пока такие результаты [https://prnt.sc/t5ovy7](https://prnt.sc/t5ovy7)

Comment: На самом деле нужна только `id` и `link`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109790/discussion-between-timur-irdyneev-and-apelsin2020).

Answer (score 0):

В общем, переделал запрос вот так и вроде как всё работает:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   new_task nt 
   JOIN
      api_task_user a 
      ON nt.id = a.id_task 
WHERE
   (a.user_id  in 
   (
      SELECT
         user_id 
      FROM
         api_task_user atu 
      WHERE
         atu.user_id = 1
      ORDER BY atu.date  
        
   )
   OR a.id_task NOT in 
   (
      SELECT
         id_task 
      FROM
         api_task_user atu 
      WHERE
         atu.id_task IN (SELECT id_task FROM  api_task_user atu WHERE  atu.user_id = 1)
         ORDER BY atu.date 
   ))
AND a.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 

GROUP BY link
```

**UPD 2:**

Посмотрел, что наши ответы выдают друг друга исключающие варианты и решил их просто совместить и вот что из этого вышло:

```
SELECT DISTINCT link FROM  
(SELECT  link  FROM new_task nt
  LEFT JOIN api_task_user atu ON atu.id_task = nt.id
WHERE nt.status = 1
  AND (atu.id is null or atu.user_id = 1)
  AND (atu.date is null or atu.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY link

UNION ALL 

SELECT
    link 
FROM
   new_task n 
   LEFT JOIN
      api_task_user atu 
      ON atu.id_task = n.id = atu.user_id = 1
WHERE
   n.status = 1 
   AND 
   (atu.user_id IS NULL )
   AND 
   (date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY OR date IS NULL)
GROUP BY link) AS fa
```

**UPD** Правильно работает только с первым пользователем, если изменить везде `id_user` = 2, результат выводится неверный, так что **вопрос остаётся открытым**